# Error displaying image in pdf directory - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Friends, I set up a shopping cart with one where I can insert several products. In addition to the cart, I needed to export this list in pdf. When generating the pdf, all items related to the product are displayed, except the product image.

I have two fields in the table where I store the image path: **path** AND **img_product**.

I have an example of the filled fields:

```
path: img/img_products/bd9399cfadbbb51639a033a6a81208bd04cf4b85
img_product: cell.jpg
```

I'm trying to generate the image this way:
Orders/pdf/download.ctp

```
<?php foreach((array) $this->request->getSession()->read('cart') as $index=>$cart): ?>

<?= $cart->has('product') ? $this->Html->image('../'.$cart->product->path.$cart->product->img_product, array('width' => '150px', 'class' => 'card-img-top')) : ''?>

<?= $cart->product->name ?>

<?php echo number_format($cart->product->price, 2, ',', '') ?></p>

Quantity: <?= $cart->quantity ?>
 
Subtotal: R$ <?php $sub = ($cart>product->price * $cart->quantity);
             echo number_format($sub, 2, ',', '');
             ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

That is, this line does not work:

```
<?= $cart->has('product') ? $this->Html->image('../'.$cart->product->path.$cart->product->img_product, array('width' => '150px', 'class' => 'card-img-top')) : ''?>
```

My folder is located at: ../webroot/img/img_products

I appreciate any comments

Comment: What URL shows up in the generated HTML for this image? Is there a good reason you're using "../" to start it instead of just "/"?

Comment: I left only '/' and the image was not displayed. When I select the product, the image appears correctly in the cart as it is in the code, but when I copy the code for download.ctp it no longer appears.

Comment: http://project.exemple.net/img/img_products/bd9399cfadbbb51639a033a6a81208bd04cf4b85tinta.jpg -> This is the url generated when I put it in the cart.

Comment: Is it correct that it's got that 40 character GUID and then "tinta.jpg" with no slash in between?

Comment: Exactly. I use the same code to display the products home page in the cart and the product image appears.

Comment: What is the full URL of a page where it is working, and the HTML from the `img` tag on that page, and what is the URL of a page where it is not working?

Comment: thank you. I checked the url and added the full url path

Answer (score 0):

See this API of CakeHelper for HTML:

https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.Helper.HtmlHelper.html#_image

```
echo $this->Html->image('cake_icon.png', ['alt' => 'CakePHP']);
```

this image path will be your_application_webroot_folder/img/cake_icon.png

So, from your question and comment I guess the path is:

> your_application_webroot_folder/img/img_products/some_unique_number/image_name.extention

The HTML link will be for that

```
echo $this->Html->image('/img_products/some_unique_number/image_name.extention');
```

Also you mentioned that one field [name= **path**] contains full path from **webroot to image directory** and other field [name= **img_product**] contain file name. So I thing you don't need  $this->Html->image. You have full image path saved in database.

You can use

```
$this->request->webroot.$cart->product->path.$cart->product->img_product
```

or you can use (if above dose not work)

```
\Cake\Routing\Router::url('/'.$cart->product->path.$cart->product->img_product,true);
```

Details: https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Routing.Router.html#_url